# Vector plot of 2d functions in mathematica

Tags: vector, plot, wolfram-mathematica, 2d, mathematica-8

I am trying to plot 1/r (r-hat) using VectorPlot in Mathematica by decomposing r-hat into x-hat and y-hat.

I am using:

```
[Chi][x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]

[Phi][x_, y_] := ArcTan[y/x]
```

and then plotting the above function in x,y plane.

But, for `x<0` and `y<0`, the vectors do not have the correct sign because the unit vectors have different sign in each of the quadrants. I tried defining a piecewise function to get around this without success.

Comment: You ought to show what you are actually plotting. In any case you may find it useful to use the two arg form of ArcTan : ArcTan[x,y] gives the angle in the correct quadrant.

Answer (score 2):

```
VectorPlot[ 1/Sqrt[x x + y y] {Cos[ArcTan[x, y]], Sin[ArcTan[x, y]]}, 
          {x, -2, 2},  {y, -2, 2},
          RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, Sqrt[x x + y y] > 1/3], 
          VectorPoints -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]